# Why are all comparison results presented?

Tags: handlebars.js

I want to compare two database data, if they are equal, then send the content to icon, but the screen directly displays all comparison results

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvuLc.png)

I hope when records.categoryId is equal to categories.id,and categories.icon will send the content to ,so that the icon will be changed.

eq.js:

```
module.exports = {
  eq: function (value1, value2, options) {
    if (value1 === value2) {
      return options.fn(this);
    } else {
      return options.inverse(this);
    }
  }
};
```

operate.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const db = require('../models')
const Record = db.Record
const Category = db.Category

router.get('/record', (req, res) => {
  Promise.all([
    Category.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'name', 'icon'],
      raw: true
    }),
    Record.findAll({
      attributes: ['id', 'name', 'date', 'amount', 'userId', 'categoryId'],
      raw: true
    })
  ])
    .then(([categories, records]) => {
      records.forEach(record => {
        record.date = record.date.toLocaleDateString('ISO', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }).replace(/\//g, '-');
      })
      const totalAmount = records.reduce((sum, record) => sum + record.amount, 0)
      res.render('index', { records, totalAmount, categories })
      console.log(categories)
    })
})
```

index.hbs:

```
{{#each records}}
      <nav id="navbar-example2" class="navbar bg-body-tertiary px-3 mb-3 bg-light">
        <div style="display: flex">
          <div style="display: flex">
            {{#each ../categories}}
            {{#eq this.id ../../categoryId}}
            <i class="{{this.icon}} fa-3x" style="vertical-align: middle"></i>
            <div class="ms-3">
              <p>{{this.name}}</p>
              <p>{{this.date}}</p>
            </div>
            {{else}}
            <i class="fa-solid fa-face-grin-beam fa-3x" style="vertical-align: middle"></i>
            <div class="ms-3">
              <p>{{this.name}}</p>
              <p>{{this.date}}</p>
            </div>
            {{/eq}}
            {{/each}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Is the path to the `record`'s `categoryId` correct or does it need a `../` removed, as in `../categoryId`?

Comment: According to your suggestion, I changed ../../categoryId to ../categoryId, and still presented all the icons in one piece of data.

Comment: I don't understand. What does "presented all the icons in one piece of data" mean?